# Import videos from Panasonic TZ 7

Tags: video, shotwell, camera

Does anyone knows a good software which will allow me to import the video I took from my digital camera Panasonic TZ7?

Shotwell imports photos perfectly from this device. However I couldn't find any software which imports the video (I tried several, among others Rapid Video Downloader). The only I could import videos is from nautilus by looking directly for the MTS files and then I have to rename the file into something which make sense.

If the software could also convert the file into some other format it is a plus, but that I can do that with VLC.

Answer (score 4):

Shotwell 0.8 will include basic video support: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/855.  You can import video from a camera and organize it in your library (tags, events) just like a photo.  No editing however, and if you double-click, it will launch a movie player.  We hope one day to host the player inside Shotwell itself: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2820

If you'd like to try it now and see if it works with your camera and its movie types, you can run from trunk: http://www.yorba.org/shotwell/install/#source

Otherwise, 0.8 should be out soon.

Comment: Thx, I'm looking forward for version 0.8 then. Do you know when a .deb packages will be available? If it is quite soon I'll wait for it, else I'll build it from the source.

Comment: We're currently working hard to complete 0.8.  If you're running Ubuntu, Yorba maintains a PPA that will have 0.8 as soon as we release it: https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa  Other distro packaging usually happens in a timely manner after we release.

Comment: Hi, I install the update! Great update. Unfortunately it doesn't work for the video with the Panasonic TZ7. The format .mts seems to cause problem for lots of software.

Comment: Could you file a ticket about the problem at http://trac.yorba.org?  If you could explain the problem you're seeing and even supply a sample video, we'll see about fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of Rapid Photo Downloader. It is written in Python. I do not know of a Python free software library that can read the MTS file format  -- at least not the two I have tried (hachoir and kaa metadata). Rapid Photo Downloader depends on being able to read the metadata from the photos and videos, so if it cannot read it, it's a big problem. If you are able to find a library that works, please let me know.

I do not know why Sony chose to implement a file format of that type.

Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for those infos. It is bad news for my problem but at least it gives me direction on where to look. If I happen to find this library I'll let you know.

Comment: The upcoming version 0.4.3 of Rapid Photo Downloader can download and rename MTS files. It calls the perl program ExifTool to handle the metadata tasks.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **[PICASA](http://picasa.google.com/)** (via Wine - it is no longer natively supported on Linux) or **[SHOTWELL](http://yorba.org/shotwell/)** to import pictures from dig cam.You can also use **[F-SPOT](http://f-spot.org/)** photo manager it is replaced by shotwell in Maverick.If you want F-Spot you can install it from it's PPA.

**Installing F-Spot**

- In terminal type the following,

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:f-spot/f-spot-ppa`
- Update your repository and then install F-Spot
  `sudo apt-get update`
  `sudo apt-get install f-spot`
- You can Launch **F-Spot** in **Applications>>Graphics** menu.

**For Importing Videos**
 you can use [gphoto2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gphoto2) [image: Install gphoto2] but that's a command line utility.The command **gphoto2 -P** will retrieve everything from the camera into the directory you are in.

Comment: Thank you but I already use Shotwell to import the pictures, I want something that imports the videos. Neither Shotwell nor Picasa work for that.

Comment: Thank you again, but I already try gphoto2 and rapid photo downloader. None of them works for the Panasonic Lumix TZ7. The video files are some .mts. I'm lookin for a software which work for this particular model. I'm asking the question after spending some time on the internet and haven't found anything.